# What is `tty10` used for in syslog-ng

Tags: syslog-ng

syslog-ng has the option to include a config snippet:

```
@include "`scl-root`/system/tty10.conf"
```

and many examples on-line include that file; but I can't understand what it's for?

The entire included file consists of:

```
@define tty10 "/dev/tty10"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, at least in the Debian version of `syslog-ng`, console output goes to `tty10`, which is supposed to be the tenth virtual console. The reason `tty10` is configured in a separate configuration file is that its value depends on the system; on Linux-based systems, it’s `/dev/tty10`, on kFreeBSD-based systems, it’s `/dev/ttya`. The package build process picks the appropriate file and installs it.

See [`README.source`](https://github.com/gcsideal/syslog-ng-debian/blob/debian/unstable/debian/README.source) for details.